# Mount Bootable USB using Powershell on Hyper-V Host

Tags: virtual-machines, hyper-v, usb-boot

Unfortunately the Hyper-V manager on my local machines returns "RPC not available" so I can't see/control my VMs.  But thankfully I can RDP into the Host machine!

I need - please - to understand the Powershell command-line commands to do the following:

Mount a USB stick and make it the bootable drive for a VM
I think part of the command is Set-VMDvdDrive -Path … but (a) how do I define which bootable iso (there are several) on the stick should be the active one (b) how can I force the VM to boot up from the USB (I need to recover a partition from an Acronis Back-Up) and (c) how do I then un-mount the USB stick for use with another VM?  Thanks Jean

Comment: Wouldn’t it be easier to figure out why hyper-v manager won’t work?

Comment: Well I've been trying for a year! At first my win7 machine carried on linking up so when I couldn't with win10 I was just lazy and went upstairs to the win7 but then it gave up as well as another win7 machine I have elsewhere.  Believe me I have tried and tried with zero success.  I even restored an Acronis image of the VMHOST that was 2 years old which didn't solve the problem (I thought I'd get back to a "vanilla" condition).  I now know how to add DVD/ISO files and change the BIOS (so that the VM boots into Acronis) but I can't figure out how to see the display! Thanks Jean

Comment: The question now is how to use vmconnect.exe to see the VM at boot - again all the explanations that I've found do not take into account that the Hyper-V 2012 r2 doesn't have a GUI Jean

Comment: Thanks for the various links - finally the VMs burst into life, ran for a week and then the RPC error turned up again.  For the ISOs and DVD I have figured it out thanks. What is puzzling is that the USB on the HOST doesn't appear (it used to) but I solved that by copying the iso files to a HDD location.  It is probably that the USB has letter F:\ and there is an F:\ drive on the local machine.  I read through the Spiceworks post mostly on time synch which I am careful to configure correctly - so far no problems there.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this article to probably fix the RPC service - https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2007303-hyper-v-manager-rpc-server-unavailable-rdp-cannot-verify-the-identity

First of all, you need to add the DVD drive to the VM. In case if DVD drive already exists by using Set-VMDvdDrive he can specify needed ISO.
For example - Set-VMDvdDrive -VMName Test -Path E:\Acronis.iso

Regarding the bootable iso definition, you always need to specify specific ISO prior to specifying just a folder.
About forcing the VM to boot up from the USB
You can make by using the ling below
https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/data-center/how-to-configure-hyper-v-vm-boot-order/

Un-mount the USB stick for use with another VM can be made by using Remove-VMDvdDrive cmdlet. To find the controller number, he can use Get-VMDvdDrive
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/hyper-v/remove-vmdvddrive?view=win10-ps